# php: modifing object properties with a matching array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to modify properties of an object (a Wordpress object) and I would like to do it by using a matching array of values.

Wordpress Object

```
array(9) {
  ["post"]=> object(stdClass)#120 (25) {
    ["labels"]=> object(stdClass)#123 (12) {
      ["name"]=> string(5) "Posts"
      ["singular_name"]=> string(4) "Post"
      ["add_new"]=> string(7) "Add New"
      ["add_new_item"]=> string(12) "Add New Post"
      ["edit_item"]=> string(9) "Edit Post"
      ["new_item"]=> string(8) "New Post"
      ["view_item"]=> string(9) "View Post"
      ["search_items"]=> string(12) "Search Posts"
      ["not_found"]=> string(15) "No posts found."
      ["not_found_in_trash"]=> string(24) "No posts found in Trash."
      ["parent_item_colon"]=> NULL
      ["menu_name"]=> string(5) "Posts"
    }
    ["description"]=> string(0) ""
    ["publicly_queryable"]=> bool(true)
    ["exclude_from_search"]=> bool(false)
    ["capability_type"]=> string(4) "post"
    ["map_meta_cap"]=> bool(true)
    ["_builtin"]=> bool(true)
    ["_edit_link"]=> string(16) "post.php?post=%d"
    ["hierarchical"]=> bool(false)
    ["public"]=> bool(true)
    ["rewrite"]=> bool(false)
    ["has_archive"]=> bool(false)
    ["query_var"]=> bool(false)
    ["register_meta_box_cb"]=> NULL
    ["taxonomies"]=> array(0) {
    }
    ["show_ui"]=> bool(true)
    ["menu_position"]=> NULL
    ["menu_icon"]=> NULL
    ["permalink_epmask"]=> int(1)
    ["can_export"]=> bool(true)
    ["show_in_nav_menus"]=> bool(true)
    ["show_in_menu"]=> bool(true)
    ["name"]=> string(4) "post"
    ["cap"]=> object(stdClass)#122 (14) {
      ["edit_post"]=> string(9) "edit_post"
      ["read_post"]=> string(9) "read_post"
      ["delete_post"]=> string(11) "delete_post"
      ["edit_posts"]=> string(10) "edit_posts"
      ["edit_others_posts"]=> string(17) "edit_others_posts"
      ["publish_posts"]=> string(13) "publish_posts"
      ["read_private_posts"]=> string(18) "read_private_posts"
      ["read"]=> string(4) "read"
      ["delete_posts"]=> string(12) "delete_posts"
      ["delete_private_posts"]=> string(20) "delete_private_posts"
      ["delete_published_posts"]=> string(22) "delete_published_posts"
      ["delete_others_posts"]=> string(19) "delete_others_posts"
      ["edit_private_posts"]=> string(18) "edit_private_posts"
      ["edit_published_posts"]=> string(20) "edit_published_posts"
    }
    ["label"]=> string(5) "Posts"
  }
etc...,
etc...,
}
```

Array of values to be changed

```
$newpost = array(
   'post' => array (
      'labels' => array(
         'name' => 'News',
         'singular_name' => 'News',
         'add_new' => 'Add New',
         'add_new_item' => 'Add New News',
         'edit_item' => 'Edit News',
         'new_item' => 'New News',
         'view_item' => 'View News',
         'search_items' => 'Search News',
         'not_found' =>  'No news found',
         'not_found_in_trash' => 'No news found in Trash',
         'parent_item_colon' => '',
         'menu_name' => 'News'
      ),
   'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ).'/template/cup.png',
   )
);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: wants to change only values of `labels` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick&dirty solution came to my mind:

I use json_decode and encode because casting the original object to an array using `(array)$wordpressObject` won't convert nested objects to arrays

```
$wordpressArray = json_decode(json_encode($wordpressObject), true);

$modifiedArray = array_merge($wordpressArray, $newpost);
```

json serialization is used again to convert between array and object recursively

```
$modifiedWordpressObject = json_decode(json_encode($modifiedArray));
```

I just wrote an example on [codepad](http://codepad.org/9WcHMinu)

It would be a cleaner solution to write a recursive algorithm to convert arrays to objects, and the other way around, but it is the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: I've forgot to mention that I used json_decode in two distinct ways: passing second parameter 'true' to it will have the function convert json into an associative array, while omitting it will return a nested stdClass (object) structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) which will combine the second array into the first, and any duplicate values in the second array overwrite the values in the first array.

Comment: The solution you posted is almost okay, but the problem is that the variable to be overwritten is not an array, but a nested object structure of stdClass.